# Windows Mobile (MFC). Scrollable text CStatic?

Tags: mfc, windows-mobile, scroll, scrollbar

I have subclassed CStatic. I have overrided the ON_WM_VSCROLL event function. But when I scroll the control with a text updates incorrectly. How to solve this problem. Or advice another way to make a scrollable panel/text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to use CEdit instead of CStatic. But if it is with transparent background then I have bugs with a background redrawing